# ARM Makefile segment explanation

Tags: makefile, kernel

Below the scripts is from `arch/arm/Makefile`.

```
ifneq ($(machine-y),)
MACHINE  := arch/arm/mach-$(word 1,$(machine-y))/
else
MACHINE  :=
endif
```

My question is:

1.Is `machine-y` a variable？

2.In addition to letters, what are the legal characters to form a variable?

3.I can't find the definition of `machine-y`, how does the compiler know the correct directory?

for example, when I use `#include <mach/gpio.h>`, the compiler must select the correct from `arch/arm/mach-at91/include/mach/gpio.h` or `arch/arm/mach-s3c2410/include/mach/gpio.h` or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(machine-y)` calls the value stored in the `machine-y` variable. In make there are [several ways](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Values) to assign a value to a variable. One of the ways variables get assigned are the ones make extracts from the environment. Quoting GNU make manual:

> Variables in make can come from the environment in which make is run. Every environment
>   variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same
>   name and value.

If you can't find `machine-y` declared in any of your makefiles and you don't pass it with the command line, it's most likely an environment variable.

Check [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables) for more info about the allowed characters for a variable name. Basicly you can use any character apart from `:`,`#`,`=` or `whitespace` as long as your shell/environment can handle them.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question:

1. Yes, machine-y is a variable in kernel's Makefile.
2. Better to look up the document of Makefile.
3. Look up the kernel file: 
   [arch/arm/Makefile](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/Makefile), You can see this code:

   `machine-$(CONFIG_ARCH_ALPINE)      += alpine
   machine-$(CONFIG_ARCH_ARTPEC)       += artpec
   machine-$(CONFIG_ARCH_AT91)        += at91`

When certain CONFIG_XXX is enabled as "y" in kernel configuration, "machine-y" variable will add the corresponding strings to it. In the case above, if CONFIG_ARCH_ALPINE is set to 'y', then machine-y will add "alpine" to itself.

Comment: three gram oil(3q)